# create separate pdf files in yii

Tags: php, yii, ghostscript, wkhtmltopdf

I am trying to create 2 separate pdf files with different content. I have the following code which creates the 2 files.

```
$invoice = Invoices::model()->findByPk($_GET['id']);
        $invoicedetail = InvoicesDetail::model()->findAll(array("condition"=>"invoiceno=".$invoice->INVOICENO . " && biditems_id is null"));
        $client = $invoice->pROJ->oRDERNO->addressesinvoices;
        $invoices = Invoices::model()->findAll(array("condition"=>"PROJID=".$invoice->PROJID . " && INVOICENO != ".$invoice->INVOICENO));

        /*$this->renderPartial("partialInvoice",
                array(
                        "invoice"=>$invoice,
                        "client"=>$client,
                        //"lookupprocesstotalArr"=>$lookupprocesstotalArr,
                        "adjustments"=>$invoices,
                        "invoicedetail"=>$invoicedetail[0]
                ),true);
        */
        $html = $this->renderPartial("partialInvoice",
                array(
                        "invoice"=>$invoice,
                        "client"=>$client,
                        //"lookupprocesstotalArr"=>$lookupprocesstotalArr,
                        "adjustments"=>$invoices,
                        "invoicedetail"=>$invoicedetail[0]),true);

        $filename_invoice = 'invoice_'.$invoice->INVOICENO.'.pdf';

        Yii::import('application.extensions.pdfable.WkHtmlToPdf');

        $pdf = new WkHtmlToPdf(array(
                'no-outline',         // Make Chrome not complain
                'margin-top'    => 10,
                'margin-right'  => 10,
                'margin-bottom' => 10,
                'margin-left'   => 10,
        ));

        $pdf->setOptions(array(
                'orientation' => 'portrait'
        ));

        // Add a HTML file, a HTML string or a page from a URL
        $pdf->addPage($html);

        // Save the PDF
        $pdf->saveAs("/tmp/$filename_invoice");

        // ... or send to client as file download
        /*if(!$pdf->send($filename)){
            throw new Exception('Could not create PDF: '.$pdf->getError());
        }*/





        $globalController = new GlobalController;
        //$project = Projects::model()->findAll(array("condition"=>"PROJID=".$_GET['PROJID']));
        //$projid = $_GET['PROJID'];
        $pdfDetail = new WkHtmlToPdf();
        $orientation = "Landscape";
        $pdfDetail->setOptions(array('orientation'=>$orientation,
                'no-outline',         // Make Chrome not complain
                'margin-right'  => 10,
                'margin-bottom' => 5,
                'margin-left'   => 10,
        ));

        //$this->layout = 'pdf';

        //get list of process stages for this project
        $lastrun = $globalController->lastRun($invoice->PROJID);
        $processstages = ExtHtml::listData($lastrun, 'ID',array('cumulative','ITEM'));

        $lookupprocesstotalArr = $globalController->lookupprocesstotal($invoice->PROJID,$processstages);

        // get all lines
        $connection = Yii::app()->db;
        $sql = "SELECT jobs.JOBNO, jobs.NAME, FSP, LSP, SHOTS, KM
                FROM hdb.jobs
                join detailsseismic on jobs.JOBNO = detailsseismic.JOBNO
                where jobs.PROJID = :pid";
        $command=$connection->createCommand($sql);
        $command->bindValue(":pid",$invoice->PROJID,PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $command->execute();
        $lines = $command->queryAll();

        $dates = array();
        foreach ($lines as $arr) {
            $sql = "SELECT jobsprocesscomplete.datedone, ITEM_fk
                    FROM hdb.jobsprocesscomplete
                    left join lookupprocess on jobsprocesscomplete.lookupprocess_id = lookupprocess.ID
                    left join biditems on lookupprocess.biditems_id = biditems.ITEMID
                    where jobno = :jobno";
            $command=$connection->createCommand($sql);
            $command->bindValue(":jobno",$arr['JOBNO'],PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $command->execute();
            $dates[$arr['JOBNO']] = $command->queryAll();
        }

        /*echo $this->renderPartial('pdf_'.$_GET['type'],array(
         'lookupprocesstotalArr'=>$lookupprocesstotalArr,
                "currency"=>$project[0]->currency0->currency,
                "projectpercent"=>$project[0]->PERCENT,
                "name"=>$project[0]->PROJECT . " - " . $project[0]->oRDERNO->cONTACTsugar->first_name . " " . $project[0]->oRDERNO->cONTACTsugar->last_name,
                "lines"=>$lines,
                "dates"=>$dates,
                "project"=>$project[0]));
        */
        $detail = $this->renderPartial('/lookupprocess/pdf_detail',array(
                'lookupprocesstotalArr'=>$lookupprocesstotalArr,
                "currency"=>$invoice->pROJ->currency0->currency,
                "projectpercent"=>$invoice->pROJ->PERCENT,
                "name"=>$invoice->pROJ->PROJECT . " - " . $invoice->pROJ->oRDERNO->cONTACTsugar->first_name . " " . $invoice->pROJ->oRDERNO->cONTACTsugar->last_name,
                "lines"=>$lines,
                "dates"=>$dates,
                "project"=>$invoice->pROJ
        ),true);


        $filename_detail = $invoice->PROJID . "_" . date("ymd-his") . ".pdf";

        // Add a HTML file, a HTML string or a page from a URL
        $pdfDetail->addPage($detail);

        // Save the PDF
        $pdfDetail->saveAs("/tmp/$filename_detail");


        shell_exec("gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -q -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=/tmp/$filename_invoice /tmp/$filename_invoice /tmp/$filename_detail");
        echo "gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -q -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=/tmp/$filename_invoice /tmp/$filename_invoice /tmp/$filename_detail";

        exit();
            /*
        // ... or send to client as file download
        if(!$pdf->send($filename_invoice)){
            throw new Exception('Could not create PDF: '.$pdf->getError());
        }
```

The problem i have is the 1st pdf that gets created is overwritten by the content of the 2nd pdf which makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know the class you are using but this code seems suspicios:

`-sOutputFile=/tmp/$filename_invoice /tmp/$filename_invoice /tmp/$filename_detail`

For me it seems that you convert 2 files into 1 output files, so logically you overwrite it!?

Comment: No, if you run two input files then they both end up in the same output file, in effect they are concatenated. It isn't clear what sharif means when he says the content of the second overwrites the first. However, if the first file does not include a showpage, then the page will not be completed when the second file is run, so the content is simply added to the existing page. Perhaps that's what he means. Of course without seeing any of the files in question, its impossible to say.

Comment: Of course you are correct that the command as given won't create two output files.....